# jQuery slideToggle function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use slideToggle to show/hide a div, but at the same time change the contents of another div.

So far I have:

```
        $('#show-advanced').click(function(){
            $("#advanced").slideToggle("fast","linear",function() {
              $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9652;');
            }, function() {
              $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9662;');
            });
        });
```

It changed the content for the first click, but on the second toggle it doesn't change it back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Fixed using:

```
            $("#show-advanced").toggle(function() {
                $('#advanced').slideDown("fast");  
                $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9652;');
            }, function() {
                $('#advanced').slideUp("fast"); 
                $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9662;');
            });
```

Comment: The HTML content is the same in both callbacks... what exactly do you want to "change back"? (*edit:* corrected). Even more relevant: `.slideToggle` does not accept two callbacks: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/.

Comment: Oops, so it was (but only on here, not in my code), however, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Because `.slideToggle` does not work the way you think it does. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Regardless, changing it to .toggle doesn't work either. Even though that definitely allows two callbacks.

Comment: `.toggle` only binds multiple event handlers to an element and alternates between them when you click on said element. It's not a substitute for `.slideToggle`.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it by using .toggle and setting show() and hide() and removing the .click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you need a combination of `.toggle` and `.slideToggle`:

```
$('#show-advanced').toggle(function() {
    $("#advanced").slideToggle("fast","linear",function() {
        $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9652;');
    });
), function() {
    $("#advanced").slideToggle("fast","linear",function() {
        $('#show-advanced').html('Advanced Options &#9662;');
    });
});
```

`.toggle` binds both functions to `#show-advanced` and alternates between them on each click.